# call the receiver when installing the application

Tags: android

I need to set an alarm when the app is installed.It is working When I put thread in
My Application class.But it only works after the app is opened.

Is there any method to listen the app installation?

Comment: Do you mean app update?

Comment: you want to notify at the time of other apps installation or your own app installation?

Comment: My own app installation

Comment: The app will not become activated until 1) user starts it from launcher 2) another app explicitly uses one of its components (explicit broadcast, content provider query). In other words, you can't run code automatically after your app is installed. Effectively, you can only listen to MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED broadcast.

Comment: @EugenPechanec "Effectively, you can only listen to `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` "  under restricted list But what is available is `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` [Broadcast Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

Comment: There is no such Intent filter like MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve this. The problem is that after first installation on device, package manager make all your components enabled="false" by default. So you can't trigger it after installation. After first lunch of app, all components will take all states that you write in AndroidManifest

Comment: Technically, it's not per receiver, the whole package has a flag `stopped=true`.

Answer (score -2):

**Update 3**

- `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` is an implicit broadcast, and **Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit**

[**Implicit Broadcast Exceptions**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. An
>   implicit broadcast is a broadcast that does not target that app
>   specifically. For example, `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is an implicit
>   broadcast, since it is sent to all registered listeners, letting them
>   know that some package on the device was replaced.
>
> However,
>   `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is not an implicit broadcast, since it is
>   sent only to the app whose package was replaced, no matter how many
>   other apps have registered listeners for that broadcast.

- **Quoting a [Google engineer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36496703#comment7)**

> To help understand what is going on, I need to clarify that the purpose of this change is not directly related to battery use, but rather to address long-standing issues we have had in the platform where devices that are under memory pressure can get in to bad thrashing states. Very often these states are due to broadcasts: some broadcast or broadcasts are being sent relatively frequently, which a lot of applications are listening to through their manifest (so need to be launched to receive it), but there is not enough RAM to keep all of those app proceses in cache, so the system ends up continually thrashing through processes each time the broadcast is sent.
>
> This is an issue regardless of whether the device is currently plugged in to power. In fact, this can more frequently be an issue on Android TV devices (which are always plugged in to power) because they tend to be fairly tight on RAM!

**Hack**

- `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast` for App install list can be used, Check hack by [CommonsWare](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html)

> If you are receiving system-sent implicit broadcasts (e.g., ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED), keep your `targetSdkVersion at 25` or lower, until we figure out better workarounds that (hopefully) do not involve polling.

**Update 0**

**Manifest.xml**

- App Install / Added.

  ```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
    <data android:scheme="package" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```
- App update

  ```
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
   <data android:scheme="package" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (data.toString().equals("package:" + "com.target.package") {
            // Do your stuff
        }
    }
```

**Update 1**

- Using `BaseActivity`

  ```
  public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

  final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null)
              return;
          switch (intent.getAction()){
              case Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED:
                  // Do your stuff.
                  break;
          }
      }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED));
  }
  }
  ```

**Update 2**

- `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL`

  > @deprecated This constant has never been used.
- `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`

  > Broadcast Action: A new application package has been installed on the device. The data contains the name of the package.
  >   **This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.**
- `Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`

  > Broadcast Action: A new version of your application has been installed
- `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`

  > Broadcast Action: A new version of an application package has been installed, replacing an existing version that was previously installed.
  >   The data contains the name of the package.

Comment: Check my update for implementing that using `BaseAcitivity`

Comment: I have tried this.But it is not working for me.Is it only working when installing from play store?

Comment: Did you try `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED` ?

Comment: Try `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`

Comment: Read my comment on the question answering why broadcasts won't work. On top of that on Android 8+ this wouldn't work anyway, see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions And another thing, PACKAGE_INSTALL is for requesting package install of e.g. a downloaded APK file, not for observing newly installed packages.

Comment: @EugenPechanec What about `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` **From Doc** `Broadcast Action: A new application package has been installed on the device. The data contains the name of the package.`

Comment: 1) It won't work on Android 8+. 2) An app doesn't get broadcasts unless the app is first started by the user or another app.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thanks for your feedback, you helped me a lot , BTW check my **update 3** about `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` mentioned on Google doc.

Comment: @HeyAlex I updated my answer, hack may be use to achieve this task,

Comment: @KhaledLela Glad I could help, sadly, none of this is going to work. OP wanted to trigger some code *at the time the app is first installed*. Your suggestions require the app already running. That's too late.

Comment: @EugenPechanec  I think `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` can be fire after app update, So you can run some logic with app update,

Comment: @EugenPechanec What about [CommonsWar hack](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html) of keep your `targetSdkVersion at 25 or lower`, Is that will work?

Comment: @KhaledLela Yes, you can run code after update. But not immediately after first install. See: 1. User installs app. 2. User runs app. 3. Only then the app can receive broadcasts. An app cannot listen to its own first time install.